Why does the results of str.extract and str.extract_all differ in polars?

Why does the result for str.extract and str.extract_all differ?
Should str.extract_all not return only the capture group, like str.extract does?
import polars as pl
#polars==0.20.30

dff = pl.DataFrame({'a': 'Label: name, Value: John, Label: car, Value: Ford'})
(dff.with_columns(pl.col('a').str.extract(    r'Label:?(.*?) Value:',1).alias('data1'),
                  pl.col('a').str.extract_all(r'Label:?(.*?) Value:').list.get(0).alias('data2')
                  )
 )

Results:
data1: " name,"
data2: "Label: name, Value:"


It is a bit odd. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12863
